# Missing EXTERN.h file when installing claws-mail on Fedora 37

Tags: fedora, perl, header-file

I've trying to compile Claws-mail but got error:

```
perl_plugin.c:54:10: fatal error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
   54 | #include <EXTERN.h>
```

I've installed perl-core perl-devel was already installed.

I can run perl -v

```
# perl -v | grep built
This is perl 5, version 36, subversion 0 (v5.36.0) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

but the problem is that there is no `/usr/lib/perl5` directory. I've found that the file is in `/usr/lib64/perl/CORE/` but I have no idea how the compile the application, the author of Claws-mail said that something is wrong with my system and he can't help me.

I've tried to add

```
export INCLUDE="/usr/lib64/perl/CORE/"
```

but the error remains. I'm not able to compile the application.

What's weird is that [list of package files](https://fedora.pkgs.org/37/fedora-updates-testing-x86_64/perl-devel-5.36.0-492.fc37.i686.rpm.html) shows that the path should be `/usr/lib/` not `/usr/lib64`.

My system was upgraded from I think Fedora 35.

Comment: I’m assuming you have a specific reason not to use the Fedora `claws-mail` package ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt I want to test the latest git version that fixed the issue I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `perl-ExtUtils-Embed`. See [the Fedora `claws-mail.spec`](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/claws-mail/blob/rawhide/f/claws-mail.spec) for reference (it’s `perl(ExtUtils::Embed)` there).

You also need to re-run `configure` after installing new packages.

(Note that your list of package files comes from the `i686` package; you need to look at [the `x86_64` package](https://fedora.pkgs.org/37/fedora-updates-testing-x86_64/perl-devel-5.36.0-492.fc37.x86_64.rpm.html) instead.)